# PHP JSON or Array to XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, json

Whats the easiest way to take a JSON or Array object and convert it to XML. Maybe I am looking in all the wrong places but I am not finding a decent answer to get me on track with doing it. Is this something I would have to somehow build myself? Or is there something like json_encode/json_decode that will take an array or json object and ust pop it out as a xml object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml

Comment: How would you want to convert a JSON/array into a XML? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check it here: [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) documentation should help you too

Regarding Json to Array, you can use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to do the same!

Answer (score 13):

Here is my variant of JSON to XML conversion.
I get an array from JSON using json_decode() function:

```
$array = json_decode ($someJsonString, true);
```

Then I convert the array to XML with my arrayToXml() function:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
$this->arrayToXml($array, $xml);
```

Here is my arrayToXml() function:

```
/**
 * Convert an array to XML
 * @param array $array
 * @param SimpleXMLElement $xml
 */
function arrayToXml($array, &$xml){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_int($key)){
            $key = "e";
        }
        if(is_array($value)){
            $label = $xml->addChild($key);
            $this->arrayToXml($value, $label);
        }
        else {
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about the easiest way. Both are relatively simple enough as I see it.

Here's a topic covering `array to xml` - [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml) and many pages covering `json to xml` can be found on google so I assume it's pretty much a matter of taste.