# How to convert Instagram API in JSON to XML with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, json

I'm currently working to convert JSON from instagram API to XML so i can fit it into my web.
Example of API URI: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=180213154.5d9f31c.67ff117fa05643aab53e209dec05eb01&count=1
Results:

```
{"pagination":{"next_url":"https:\/\/api.instagram.com\/v1\/users\/3\/media\/recent?access_token=180213154.5d9f31c.67ff117fa05643aab53e209dec05eb01\u0026count=1\u0026max_id=627998676974834410_3","next_max_id":"627998676974834410_3"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"attribution":null,"tags":[],"type":"image","location":{"latitude":35.66343355,"name":"STREAMER COFFEE COMPANY Shibuya","longitude":139.703916256,"id":85987},"comments":{"count":253,"data":[{"created_time":"1389227943","text":"Found a massive flaw in your security settings regarding blocking users. How can I get in contact with someone about it? It's not covered in the help centre.","from":{"username":"sorehands","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_373015_75sq_1388722624.jpg","id":"373015","full_name":"Jim Madden"},"id":"629212055559213459"},{"created_time":"1389229366","text":"Can i ask why my ins account only can follow 600 people???","from":{"username":"ginameng9208","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_411563068_75sq_1389151537.jpg","id":"411563068","full_name":"Gina"},"id":"629223987146133573"},{"created_time":"1389229770","text":"Green Hornettt","from":{"username":"christian_anthony64","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_602175818_75sq_1388897977.jpg","id":"602175818","full_name":"Christian Anthony Hynick"},"id":"629227377116844283"},{"created_time":"1389232974","text":"Do you enjoy people asking you random questions with no connection to the photo you posted? @kevin @garrett","from":{"username":"jimbo","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_73292_75sq_1329450021.jpg","id":"73292","full_name":"James Mellors"},"id":"629254258520232796"},{"created_time":"1389234525","text":"Delete blah420hhhh ASAP","from":{"username":"mariaglam27","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_22333079_75sq_1388097173.jpg","id":"22333079","full_name":"\ud83c\udf1fMARIA\ud83c\udf1f"},"id":"629267267019870954"},{"created_time":"1389244448","text":"It's like ferns","from":{"username":"jellybaby304x","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_875122748_75sq_1388550325.jpg","id":"875122748","full_name":"Jaime"},"id":"629350503418958807"},{"created_time":"1389246207","text":"How did you do that? That's so awesome.","from":{"username":"cutepets5698","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","id":"905777437","full_name":"cutepets5698"},"id":"629365258560999971"},{"created_time":"1389249463","text":"Thank you for creating an amazing platform for me to produce and consume raw media!","from":{"username":"goldaviators","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_14617395_75sq_1388635603.jpg","id":"14617395","full_name":"Shelton"},"id":"629392576180392401"}]},"filter":"Valencia","created_time":"1389083297","link":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/i3GXgsgBLq\/","likes":{"count":15972,"data":[{"username":"tylermccormack16","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_630160402_75sq_1386021156.jpg","id":"630160402","full_name":"Tyler Mccormack"},{"username":"badetcor","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_493933756_75sq_1375603183.jpg","id":"493933756","full_name":"badetcor"},{"username":"cherrygandararivera","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/anonymousUser.jpg","id":"924993914","full_name":"cherrygandararivera@yahoo.com"},{"username":"_noah2003","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_637433886_75sq_1383646066.jpg","id":"637433886","full_name":"FOLLOW ME BITCH!!!!!!"}]},"images":{"low_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com\/8db13ee2777511e3a801121e0f202bd6_6.jpg","width":306,"height":306},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com\/8db13ee2777511e3a801121e0f202bd6_5.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"standard_resolution":{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com\/8db13ee2777511e3a801121e0f202bd6_8.jpg","width":640,"height":640}},"users_in_photo":[],"caption":{"created_time":"1389083297","text":"Still dreaming of the latte art in Tokyo \ud83c\uddef\ud83c\uddf5","from":{"username":"kevin","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_3_75sq_1325536697.jpg","id":"3","full_name":"Kevin Systrom"},"id":"627998677444596365"},"user_has_liked":false,"id":"627998676974834410_3","user":{"username":"kevin","website":"","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_3_75sq_1325536697.jpg","full_name":"Kevin Systrom","bio":"","id":"3"}}]}
```

How i convert it to XML like below with PHP.

```
<products>
<category categoryName="Electronics">
    <product productName="Camera Lenses Collection" productID="DSCF0001" thumbPath="thumbs/Electronics/camera_lenses_collection-other.jpg" productPrice="250.50">
        <details>
        <![CDATA[
        <p class="four">You can place your HTML CSS formatted content</p>
    <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. <span class="three">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard </span>dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley  of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived  not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and  more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker  including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p><img src="images/Electronics/camera_lenses_collection-other.jpg" /><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. <span class="three">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard </span>dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley  of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived  not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and  more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker  including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> 
    ]]></details>
</product>
</category>
```

Comment: you can refer this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544840/php-json-or-array-to-xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this [XML Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer). You can see another question here with some example answers that might help. [Is there some way to convert json to xml in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856833/is-there-some-way-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-php?rq=1) Likewise you can use json_decode.

Comment: Hi Pjack, i faced a problem while creating XML with foreach. Look at this for XML Results: http://pastebin.com/ubGGyp9b (I can't paste xml formatted here).
The problem is:
Value productName="Sushi Homemade " and productPrice="50.000 " is just for productID="002". But why the value also filled to next productID >= 002.

Comment: Nevermind, im forget to add ifelse condition. Thanks for your response :)