# how to convert json response data to xml

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml

this response get in a one variable,how to convert JSON response in xml in php script

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"15",
         "color_code":"#D9DD29",
         "font_color_code":"#ed1b1b",
         "type":"Big Chunes",
         "is_fade":"1",
         "is_Active":"1",
         "delay_time":"0"
      },
      {  
         "id":"58",
         "color_code":"#19A87D",
         "font_color_code":"#ffffff",
         "type":"Demo",
         "is_fade":"1",
         "is_Active":"1",
         "delay_time":"0"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/31674872/7155723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function array2xml($array, $xml = false){

    if($xml === false){
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<result/>');
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            array2xml($value, $xml->addChild($key));
        } else {
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $xml->asXML();
}

$jSON = json_decode($raw_data, true);

$xml = array2xml($jSON, false);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
```